# Can I use light sensor to measure period between flashes of light? Is there any class that I can use or

Tags: java, android, mobile

Can I use *light sensor* to measure period between **flashes of light**? Is there any class that I can use or should I code it by myself? Can anyone provide me with something to start with?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    difference = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

    if (event.values[0] >= 50) {
        newdifference = System.nanoTime() - (startTime + difference);

        if (newdifference >= 2450 && newdifference < 2550) {
            dotordash = ".";

        }

        else if (newdifference > 7450 && newdifference < 7550) {
            dotordash = "-";
        }
        code += dotordash;
    }

    show.setText(" " + code);
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: I searched through developer website but all what I get is general information about how to use the sensor, what I want is a specific thing which is how to calculate the period between two flashes of light when received by the sensor. I want to be able to calculate this difference every time to set an action dependent on it. Thank you

Comment: That is what you have to do yourself. The docs just show you how to access and utilize the sensors

Comment: please check my code, I want to know why "-" or "." are displayed 6 time per flash while they should only be displayed once per flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do with `nanoTime()` is basically totally random regarding to get a dot or a hash. There're two things you're interested in:

- If the light gets bright enough to count as "flash is on" or "flash is off". This is in the value of the `SensorEvent` and you already check that with `event.values[0] >= 50`. To put it in one line of code:

  `boolean isFlashOn = (event.values[0] >= 50)`
- Second is to count the time between changes of `isFlashOn`. You get the actual time of a event **only** from the `SensorEvent` itself as it might take some time, till the event is delivered to you. So never try to compare with the current system time.

Saying all that there's still a chance, that the light sensor delivers noise, which would be measure of darkness during a flash. If this is the case, you would need some kind of noise filtering which can get tricky, especially with something with very short durations like a flash. See [Signal noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_noise) for a discussion about noise and noise filtering.